# How to check if the click was directly in an element or some of its children only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't want clicks on children other than some, and the parent div itself to trigger any events.

Please see this, which does not do what I want:

https://jsfiddle.net/k12e8rgt/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#parent').on('click', function(event) {
    alert("you clicked directly on me!");
  });

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k12e8rgt/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `event.target`

Example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").on("click", function(event) {
    alert("You click on : " + event.target.tagName)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>this is Div
  <p>This is p</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps, can you elaborate? The "not here" child can have many childs inside, and in that case event.target will be one of those, so I can't simply compare if event.target == .not.here.

Comment: you can give the div a unique id / class / data attribute and that can be obtained through the event.target object, as that's the dom element actually clicked... then you can know if the attribute is what you want, and trigger the action if that exists, or not if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

- Assign a class to elements which are to be `ignored`
- Use [**`.hasClass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class

```js
$('#parent').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass('ignore')) {
    alert("Ignore !");
  } else {
    alert("Do something!");
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
#child2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">it should trigger here
  <div id="child1">and here</div>
  <div id="child2" class="ignore">but not here, and there are many of this kind</div>
</div>
```

**If** there are set of `ids` which are to be `ignored`, use `event.target.id` property and test the value against it!

```js
$('#parent').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'child2' || event.target.id === 'child3') {
    alert("Ignore !");
  } else {
    alert("Do something!");
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
#child2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child3 {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
#child1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">it should trigger here
  <div id="child1">and here</div>
  <div id="child2">but not here, and there are many of this kind</div>
  <div id="child3">but not here, and there are many of this kind</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target`...

https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Also, for event handling in general with jQuery...

https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/